# How to change the Go to App button?

Tags: php, facebook

I can see when I want to use some applications they have some 'Ok, Read the Article' instead of 'Go to App' button, how can I change it on my application?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Facebook's Actions and Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#actions-objects).

- [Define Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/)
- [Define Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/)
- [Define Aggregations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/)

You also have to submit them for [approval](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/).

Comment: Yes, I did it but how to change the button text from that?. I got approved <app-ns>:read action. I'm not using default news.read action.

Comment: If you're not using one of the defaults, you likely won't be able to change it.

Comment: I'm still getting 'Go to App' after changing to news.reads. Do I need to change anything else?.