# How to change the App button value?

Tags: php, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the Go to App button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476189/how-to-change-the-go-to-app-button)

I need to change

[image]

name to

[image]

How can I do that?.

Comment: You [just asked that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476189/how-to-change-the-go-to-app-button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using one of Facebook's default action types, you likely won't be able to affect that button's text at all.

Comment: I changed my action type to default, news.reads but still not showing as Ok, Read Article. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working yet, any thoughts?